# UniqueEntity validation for OneToMany related entities

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine, constraints, one-to-many

I have the following validations defined for `ProductType, ProductTypeAttributes` (OneToMany):

```
Bike\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductType:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        productTypeAttributes:
            - Valid: ~
Bike\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductTypeAttribute:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [attribute, productType]
            errorPath: attribute
            message: 'Attributes must be different for the same product type.'
```

There is a unique key for `ProductTypeAttributes`: `attribute,productType`.

I am using embedded forms (collection type) for `ProductTypeAttributes` with the possibility to add/remove items. The validation seems to work only for the already existent records in the db, happening only if I am adding a new related entity which will trigger the unique key violation for a record.

The problem is the validation doesn't work when adding two completely new related entities, with the same attribute/productType. In this case I get the "duplicate entry" exception.

So the validation checks only through db records using default `findBy` method, but not against newly added records themselves for duplicates.

Any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not through the default UniqueEntity validator. You'll have to manually create a second validator that works on the entire ProductType entity and validates that none of the new (unsaved) Attributes are the same.

Check out Symfony´s cookbook on how to make your own validator:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: I thought about creating a custom validation, where I can look for duplicates, but shouldn't doctrine know to handle this within the transaction (where multiple insertions are done)?